# How to change the user in ES File Explorer

Tags: permissions

I use ES File Explorer on my Android phone (Lollipop).

When I connect to my NAS, it prompts me for a user name and password. I enter this, and I connect. However, I now need to connect as a different user.

I'm not prompted again for the user name/password, ES File Explorer and remembered these settings but, I can't find how to clear this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open ES File Explorer.  Head to cloud,  or FTP (Depending on which you are using,  and hold on the server.  An option along the bottom called "edit server"  will show up.  Click it, exit as necessary,  and press OK.